# What do you call a person who admits that she has a bad side and a good side too?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who considers himself both bad and good? Bob, for example, burns his enemy's house as revenge, after which he says, "Good Bob wants to apologize, but bad Bob  wanted revenge." What would you call Bob?

Comment: This is a question about psychological terminology & has nothing to do with English grammar and usage. I would call "Bob" an idiot looking for forgiveness for what he is about to do or someone who thinks that he can cop an insanity plea based on **the two faces of Bob**. This isn't a word-choice question because there is no choice. This isn't a meaning question because there's no word for anyone to give a meaning to. There's only a description & a request for a word. This kind of question should be disallowed.

Comment: I'd call Bob a dualist.

Comment: bipolar / manic.

Comment: @BillFranke The question has simply been tagged incorrectly by a newbie. It is a [tag:single-word-request] and is on topic for this site. That said, [many](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) do find them trying.

Comment: This is a theological question as Judaism would call such a person "human" -- all people are created with separate impulses to do good and to do evil.  See Deut. 30:15-20.  How they choose to act is called "free will."

Answer (score 4):

You could call him a “Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde”, from the names of the [Robert Louis Stevenson character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr_Jekyll) with the split personality.

The terms are often used to describe someone who struggles with good and evil. For example, in  the play *[A Distance from Calcutta](http://books.google.com/books?id=4fEqKUbR32YC&pg=PA35&dq=%22a%20Dr%20Jekyll%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Em1CUfDoHar02gWpkoEg&ved=0CFwQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22a%20Dr%20Jekyll%22&f=false)*, one of the characters says:

> You see what he's like? You see his temper? A **Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde** ... you can be sure of that. I feel sorry for you, Ann.

The phrase is used in [works of non-fiction](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hckys7gpwl4C&pg=PA315&dq=%22a%20Dr%20Jekyll%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Um5CUc7JIYji2QXbxYGIBA&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBTgU#v=onepage&q=%22a%20Dr%20Jekyll%22&f=false) as well.